# Recreate removed cached images when accessed directly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say you have an app that automatically resizes images when a page is loaded, then it stores those in an image cache folder with the dimensions as a suffix, so it won't have to recreate the image next time.

That's a sweet function there.

Now for whatever reason someone hotlinks the image and they're all like "man, that's a cool image. I'm going to use it." and you're like "okay, have fun"  but then because you have a very slight case of severe alzheimer's, you cleared your cache.

Man, that sucks.

All hot links are broken!

But, there's a solution up ahead in the distance. If we could somehow use php and mod_rewrite/.htaccess to route the non-existant/404 image to a script that will take the filename as a parameter, parse out the dimensions and original filename, then not only replace and resize the lost image but also echo out the image data with the headers, then that would be sweet.

My question. What would the rewrite rule that I use in .htaccess to route image requests that 404 look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# request isn't a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# request ends with an image extension, so route to php script
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico)$ /image.php?filename=$1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: This works excellent. Except that I had to remove the line with !-f.